# Отсутствует оператор, соответствующий операндам

Tags: c++, операторы

Выдает ошибку отсутствует оператор соответствующий операндам.Что переделать?

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>


using namespace std;

int main() {
    ifstream file("text.txt");
    string s;
    char c, find;
    int pos = 0, i = 0, rows_count = 0;

    while (!file.eof()) {
        file.get(c);
        s.push_back(c);
    }
    file.close();

    cout << "enter a world for find: ";
    cin >> find;
    {
        for (i = 0; i < s.size(); ++i)
            if (s == find) //компилятор указывает ошибку здесь
                cout << "Finded in " << i << " simvol position" << endl;
            else
                cout << "Word not finded " << endl;
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Выдает ошибку отсутствует оператор
> соответствующий опежрандам

В классе std::string нет перегруженного оператора сравнения с символьным типом char, поэтому оператор == не применим в данном случае. Чтобы устранить ошибку, нужно после s поставить квадратные скобки:

```
if  (s[i] == find)
```

Что дословно означает: берем символ, находящийся в строке s в позиции i и сравниваем его с find. Собственно, для этого вы и написали цикл for выше.